# Can't access reference to typescript method from DataTable method

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I am connecting a datatable from datatables.net with my Angular app where I am trying to get data fra a row in typescript. I can see the data through the console, but I can't reach my other methods in the class.

So i tried to .bind(this) on the table.on() method but did not help.

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

// Edit record
  table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
    let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = table.row($tr).data();
    console.log(data[0]);
    this.navigateTo(data[0]);
  }.bind(this));
```

But i receive following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

So I need a symbol from data from data[0] to pass on to another component. But then this error shows.

What am I doing wrong? I guess it is something with the .bind(this), but i am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event handling in jQuery relies on changing the `this` in the scope of the function. When you attach the click event handler to `.edit`, jQuery will try to call the handler passing the clicked DOM element as `this`. That is necessary for your code cause you are using the clicked element in `$(this).closest('tr');`.

When you add `.bind(this)` you prevent jQuery from "replacing" the `this` when calling the handler. In this case `this` will be the same as it was when `.bind(this)` was called.

There are a few ways you can workaround this situation:

1. Create a reference to the outer `this`:

   ```
   var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
   var that = this;

   // Edit record
     table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
       let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       var data = table.row($tr).data();
       console.log(data[0]);
       that.navigateTo(data[0]);
     });
   ```
2. Keep the binding, but use the event target instead of `this`:

   ```
   var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

   // Edit record
     table.on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
       let $tr = $(event.target).closest('tr');
       var data = table.row($tr).data();
       console.log(data[0]);
       this.navigateTo(data[0]);
     }.bind(this));
   ```
3. Use arrow function to keep the outer this, and get the clicked element from the event:

   ```
   var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

   // Edit record
     table.on('click', '.edit', event => {
       let $tr = $(event.target).closest('tr');
       var data = table.row($tr).data();
       console.log(data[0]);
       this.navigateTo(data[0]);
     });
   ```

Comment: Thiago. Thanks for your help and great answer. Everything is good now! :) Went with option number 3.